# table view scrolls under view above it not with it

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, view, scroll

I have a view at the top of the screen(below the navigation bar).
Below the view is a table view.

The problem is that when I scroll down through the table, it scrolls under the view at the top of the screen.
I would like for the view at top to scroll along with the table view.

Can anybody recommend some direction?

I tried to google it and nothing useful came up. I hope I am explaining it well enough here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be solved easily. Please try to put the view into the tableview as a subview. You could add a view to TableView at top and bottom. The view added to Tableview will be scrolled.

Comment: Even if I have a header for the table view?
I tried to pull the view in the table view and I can't see it anymore.

Comment: Strange, but it works. I just tried in Playground. If I remember correctly, this method didn't work in earlier versions of iOS.

Comment: Oh my, this worked! I wouldn't have expected to be able to do this. Thanks!
I marked your answer as correct as you were the first to suggest this.

Comment: small follow up question bugging me right now: what if I need to hide the view?
right now it leaves with with a blank space at the top of the table.
how to i hide the view and make the table start from where the view was?

Comment: You can change the height of the view with the instance of it in code. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept scrolling implementing `scrollViewDidScroll` method in your table view delegate and in this method update `frame` (or constraints, if you are using AutoLayout) of this overlaying view.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions that I can think of here:

***Solution 1***: Add a prototype cell in your table, and use that as the view you want to display at the topmost part of your table. Then in your code, you can load that cell at the index 0 to ensure that it will be loaded at the topmost part of your table.

Code sample:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        TopMostTableCell *tableCell = (TopMostTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TopMostTableCell"];

        return tableCell;
    }

    else
    {
        OtherTableCell *tableCell = (OtherTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"OtherTableCell"];

        return tableCell;
    }
}
```

***Solution 2***: Add the view you want to be the topmost part of the table which you can scroll along to the table header.

You can add the view through coding, or loading the nib file.

Code sample:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200, 50)];

    //loading from nib file
    UIView *headFromNib = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Header" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

    [header setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    _table.tableHeaderView = header;
}
```

Hope this helps you. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
If the table has a header, should I add the view to the header or directly to the table?

Comment: You should add that to the header. Otherwise If you have a separate layout for your header, and you want that view(you are talking about) on top of your table header, then you might as well join the layout of your header and that view and then put that joined view(header + the view) at the header section of the table.